# UIView frame animations in container break when adding children view controllers

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, touch

So I have a Custom Container View Controller that I'm setting up and I have a custom animation that is suppose to happen when you swipe between the children view controllers that was working perfectly up until I took the temp UILabels out of the placeholder view and added the view from the child view controller to the place holder. If I comment out the "addSubview" lines then the animation works perfectly again, but obvious I don't have any children which is kinda the point...

Now I say that the animation doesn't work, but that's not entirely true because anything linked to something that I added at init (ie the notify and user placeholders and children) animate perfectly. The feed view is visable under them though and the header and footer bars only budge sometimes. The will randomly twitch if I move the touch the y axis as well as the x... it's weird.

init code for setting up and adding the child VCs:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    self.feedVC = (NiTActionFeedViewController*)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Feed"];
    self.feedVC.delegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:self.feedVC];
    self.feedVC.view.frame = self.mainPage.bounds;//mainPage view is the only UIView that is placed in the IB as template for the other views (so I don't have to worry about resizing for 4" retina^^;)
    [self.mainPage addSubview:self.feedVC.view];
    [self.feedVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //notify
    self.notifyPage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.mainPage.frame, -kPageShift, 0)];// this is one of the placeholder views
    [self.notifyPage setClipsToBounds:YES];

    self.notifyVC = (NiTNotificationViewController*)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Notify"];
    self.notifyVC.delegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:self.notifyVC];
    self.notifyVC.view.frame = self.notifyPage.bounds;
    [self.notifyPage addSubview:self.notifyVC.view];
    [self.notifyVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //user
    self.userPage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.mainPage.frame, kPageShift, 0)];
    [self.userPage setClipsToBounds:YES];

    self.userVC = (NiTUserViewController*)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserScreen"];
    self.userVC.delegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:self.userVC];
    self.userVC.view.frame = self.userPage.bounds;
    [self.userPage addSubview:self.userVC.view];
    [self.userVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.view addSubview:self.notifyPage];
    [self.view addSubview:self.userPage];

     //and then re-add the header and footer views so that the children don't cover them^^
    [self.view addSubview:self.headerbar];
    [self.view addSubview:self.headerButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.footerbar];
    [self.view addSubview:self.footerButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.rightPageIndicator];
    [self.view addSubview:self.leftPageIndicator];
```

and here is the touchesMoved code(if you need more then this let me know, but even on end they don't budge):

```
if (touches.count > 0) {
        UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        float diff = currentPoint.x - startingPoint.x;

        //currentScreen is an enum that I set on load and on trigger of the screen change so I always know what screen is showing and it is always accurate
        //this line is just to make sure we don't go past the "edge" of the screen and is working perfectly
        if ((self.currentScreen - (diff<0?-1:1)) > userScreen||(self.currentScreen - (diff<0?-1:1)) < notifScreen) {
            return;
        }


            self.headerbar.frame = CGRectOffset(initheaderbar, (int)(kHeaderBarShift * (diff/kPageShift)), 0);
            self.headerButton.frame = CGRectOffset(initheaderButton, kHeaderButtonShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0);
            self.footerbar.frame = CGRectOffset(initfooterbar, kFooterBarShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0);
            self.mainPage.frame = CGRectOffset(initmainPage, kPageShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0);
            self.userPage.frame = CGRectOffset(inituserPage, kPageShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0);
            self.notifyPage.frame = CGRectOffset(initnotifyPage, kPageShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0);

        //this always updates and looks right even though nothing changes on the screen
            NSLog(@"move main:%@(%@)\nnotify:%@\nuser:  %@",NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectOffset(initmainPage, kPageShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0)),NSStringFromCGRect(self.mainPage.frame),NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectOffset(initnotifyPage, kPageShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0)),NSStringFromCGRect(CGRectOffset(inituserPage, kPageShift * (diff/kPageShift), 0)));

            lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }else{
        //never seen this called thus why I have it here so I know if something mind blowing has happened
        NSLog(@"W.T.F");
    }
```

Now, the last piece you probably need to know is that I have a "touchController" protocol set up that can have "touchDelegates" set up in all the children that point to the parent so that any touches that they receive get forwarded to the Container VC and they are all forwarding properly so that's not it (and the animations wouldn't work at all if that was the case)...

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope! Seriously, could use any help that anyone could give^^;

**REQUESTED INFO**
I am pretty much animating everything on the screen. I can not post screenshots or a video because of the nature of the project, but hopefully you will be able to flow along with me with the diagram below(sorry, I'm not photoshop expect =P). The only thing not shown in the diagram is the headerButton, but basically it's just on top of the headerBar and moves at a slightly slower pace as it doesn't move as far. The idea of the design is that if you swipe in a direction it slides the screen in the opposite direction (like you would expect) and the header and footer bars slide at a different speed because they are shorter so the items on them are always visible, but have a "cool" effect in showing which side/page you are on. (neither bar ever shows an "end" on the screen, the "end" gets right to the edge of the screen, but never comes onto it) All of the constants are just that. kPageShift is the screen width (320). The rest are how far they need to move between screens, since they are all different sizes besides the pages. If you need more info please let me know!

[image]

Comment: The wording of your question is very confusing to me. Can you be very specific about which views exactly are animating, and which ones are not? Please provide a list based on their property names as used in your code. Also, there are some defined constants that you are using as multipliers when calculating your frame offsets - what are these values? Can you provide any screenshots that demonstrate the kind of animation effect you are trying to achieve or at least show the layout of the views so that we can get a better idea of what is going on in your app?

Comment: Where is your animation code? By removing which statements you claim it animates perfectly? What kind of animation you are looking here? Your touch method doesn't seem to indicate animation but look just sudden shift of position.

Comment: the animation code is in the touchesMoved touchesEnded events. It is these lines: [self.mainPage addSubview:self.feedVC.view];[self.notifyPage addSubview:self.notifyVC.view];[self.userPage addSubview:self.userVC.view]; The screen did/should slide with your finger and the header and footers parallax with it a bit. I added an animation block at one point, but it didn't help anything.

Comment: If the headerBar or footerBar were to move along the x-axis, I would not be able to tell that they had moved because visually the whole bar appears the same (in the diagram it is a solid blue bar). Is your bar actually moving but only visually appearing to not be moving? Also - you have some NSLog code that is printing out the calculated CGRects, however it is not printing out the CGRects of the headerBar and footerBar frames. If I understand your question correctly, it's the bars that aren't moving properly - so why not print out their CGRects in the NSLog to see what their frames are?

Comment: Try something like this, let us know what you find... NSLog(@"headerbar.frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.headerbar.frame));

Comment: Done that(thought I mentioned it in the description above, but maybe not). The frame reports that it is changing and is set to exactly what it should be, but there is no visual indication of it. It's the bars and the "mainPage" that are not moving like they are suppose to (only the notifyPage and userPage are).

Comment: You mentioned above in your code that you are NSLogging, but the logging shown in your code is NOT as I have described. I have tried to reproduce your issue in a test project, but I can't reproduce it because I don't have all of your code - only some of it. My hunch is that there must be some miscalculation of the frame during touchesMoved, but I cannot test because I don't have your exact project code.

Comment: You asked me to log the change in the frame of headerbar and footerbar, but I am logging the change of the frame of the mainPage ... which is also animated...So what's the difference? all 3 are not showing animations properly despite at least one being changed properly. If it helps the initblah frames are set in the touchesBegan event. Thank you for trying, because of the nature of the project I can't give all the code/project. If you let me know what you are missing I may could fill in the gaps. If I have time I may try to make a small demo to show it, but may not have time.

Comment: If you are changing the frames of the notifyPage and the userPage and those are animating properly, then the other views should animate properly as well assuming that their frames are being calculated correctly. Other factors could be if you are using any autoresizing mask or constraints in IB on the three objects that won't animate properly. I'm asking you to NSLog each individual frame explicitly because each frame is unique and even though you assume there's no difference, they ARE unique and it can't hurt to be absolutely sure that the values are correct for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: I logged those as well, and their frames are updating/setting properly as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off AutoLayout in your Storyboard file.

The constraints which have been setup are causing that random twitch which you talked about.

[image]

Comment: forgot that I had moved this controller out into an external nib file and had only turn autolayout off in the storyboard! My derp is your gain^^ Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help. I have faced this issue so many times that I have realised that auto layout breaks almost all kinds of custom animation code. The constraints really try to make life hell for a developer.